# Wi-Fi is off. My hardware switch is broken

Tags: internet, dell, 19.04, intel, wifi-hardware-switch

I picked up a cheap laptop and threw Ubuntu 19.04 on it. And it says wifi switch off. But the thing is the hardware switch is completely broken off. Is there anyway I can get past a hard blocked wifi switch.

rfkill list

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ rfkill list
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Comment: I'm afraid no operating system in the world is going to fix a broken hardware. I would get a $10 USB WiFi dongle and use that.

Comment: For sure please add output of `rfkill list` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1199476/edit).

Comment: I'm afraid it's probably not going to be possible - [this question from a few years ago asking the same thing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768403/is-it-possible-to-bypass-a-hardware-wifi-switch-if-rfkill-unblock-all-does-no) didn't get answer. If you have the skills to do so, opening your laptop and physically fixing it is probably the only way to get it to work - or you can get a USB WiFi adapter.